# Double quote giving issues in update query

Tags: postgresql

The query at `'-'` is not able to execute .Please help.

```html
    update table_attributes set foreign_table=
    '(select users_roles.*, concat(persons.firstname,'-',roles.r_name) as name from users_roles users_roles left join users users on users_roles.user_id = users.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN persons on persons.user_id=users.user_id 
    left join roles roles on users_roles.role_id = roles.role_id as users_roles ' where att_id=24
```

Comment: I don't have a postgres instance to check but you might need to replace the second parameter in the concat method with ''-'' (double the quotes), or \'-\'

Comment: This did not worked. I have tried it before .

Comment: @dgebert Escaping in literals is done with `''` - notice double apostrophes, not a double quote (`"`).

Comment: @Yogus What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi, right, In my answer I've suggested using  double apostrophes, but it's not visible without proper formatting, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dollar-Quoted String](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-syntax.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) syntax - it is very safe and readable - and do not forget the closing bracket before `as users_roles`.

```sql
update table_attributes set foreign_table =
$FT_SQL$(
 select users_roles.*, concat(persons.firstname,'-',roles.r_name) as "name" 
   from users_roles users_roles 
   left join users users on users_roles.user_id = users.user_id 
   left join persons on persons.user_id=users.user_id 
   left join roles roles on users_roles.role_id = roles.role_id
) as users_roles;$FT_SQL$
where att_id=24;
```

Please note that some aliases are redundant.